# remote jprofiler integration with mule

Tags: mule, jprofiler

How can I integrate Jprofiler UI running in my laptop connect to mule server running in a remote server. I had installed jprofiler remotely in the server box and tried to run jpenable to attach to the mule server, and it's unable to. Here is the error I'm getting.

`Connecting to org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerBootstrap start0 [9828] ...
Please select the profiling mode:
GUI mode (attach with JProfiler GUI) [1, Enter]
Offline mode (use config file to set profiling settings) [2]
1
ERROR: Attaching is not supported: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:100)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.b(ejt:265)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:252)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:222)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.a(ejt:118)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.g(ejt:81)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.main(ejt:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 1):

The attach mechanism in the JVM is not very reliable, there are circumstances that can cause it to fail that are outside the control of a tool vendor.

First, check if jpenable is run as the same user as the application that you want to profile. If using the same users has no effect, you have to add the VM parameter for profiling to the startup command of your application and restart it.

You can get that that parameter in JProfiler by invoking

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

and following the steps in the wizard.

Comment: Running jprofiler as the java app's user (not as root) was what did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change permissions to /usr/lib/jvm(set it 777) to probe